# How many users webrtc audio or video broadcasting can afford?

Tags: javascript, html, web, webrtc, broadcasting

I am using webrtc  technology to create a video and audio broadcast (one to many) and it is working very well now for 10 listeners or viewers, but can't determine if this is gonna succeed or not for large number of viewers or listeners
Considering that I don't use any media servers, the data comes out of the broadcaster PC to the listeners, the server only links listeners with the broadcaster
The question here is that gonna succeed for large number of users ?
How many listeners can this method afford  if you have experimented that before?
And are there any services like mine use the same technology ?

Comment: I guess its as simple as `maxlisteners = broadcastersBandwith / streamSize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bloggeek.me/media-server-for-webrtc-broadcast/ provides an in-depth answer to this and explains some of the considerations you need to make.